# Is it gramatically correct to use past tense when referring to the future?

Tags: tenses

I was doing some testing on my local machine that involved changing my system clock to a future date.

When I compiled my project, I received warnings that read:

> **Warning**: *xxxx.class* was edited in the future.

To me, saying "**was edited in the future**" is a contradiction of terms. However, given the limitations of time, I suppose it does make sense.

Is it grammatically correct to say something has been edited in the future? Would the answer to this change if time travel were possible?

Comment: they could have said: "Warning: xxx.class was edited using a future date." or  "warning. xxx.class has been edited using a future date"

Comment: The more usual meaning of 'oxymoron' is 'something that appears like a contradiction but is found not to be on deeper analysis'. To me, saying "was edited in the future" is a contradiction in terms. If you are playing the time-travel card, you need to move to a different SE.

Comment: Can I get tips on how to make my question better suited for this site? I welcome criticism, but a down vote with no explanation is not helpful to me.

Comment: Sorry, the short answer to your question is no, but I've fixed what I could on the voting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb tense is correct. The edit occurred in the past. The phrase "in the future" is shorthand for "with a timestamp that is after the current clock setting".